# Calculate Probability Of a Failure

Tags: probability

If a piece of computer equipment will fail once a year and be unavailable for 1.5 hours, how do I calculate the probability of the failure occurring each hour of every day

Comment: Could you tell us the source of your question?  Homework? Work assignment? Idle curiosity?  As stated, there seems to be a lot of ambiguity as to what is meant.

Comment: How many hours are in a year?  Do you count all of them, or only "working" hours of some kind?

Comment: Silly remark, but since it will only fail once a year, it is *certain* that it won't fail each hour of every day.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is:

> **"What is the probability of a failure occurring in a given hour?"**

We will count the failure event itself, which happend once per year, giving:
Number of hours in a year = 365d * 24h = **8,760h**
Number of failures per hour = 1 failure per year / 8,760h/y = 0.0001142 failures per hour, or:

**0.01142% chance of experiencing a failure in a given hour.**

If the question was:

> **"What is the probability of having the computer be unavailable within a given hour?"**

(as is implied by the duration given), then:

The probability of the single failure overlapping with a given hour is:

Number of days in a year = **365d/y**
Number of days of unavailability = 1.5h / 24h/d = **0.0625d** of unavailability per year

**0.01712% probability of having some unavailability within a given hour.**